# What's the equivalent of INSERT ... ON CONFLICT that first tries update?

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I've been using `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` to insert/update data. The question I have is that I know that most of the time, I will want to do an update: for every day, update a counter. If there's no data for that date, then create the row. That creation will only happen once (obviously), but the update could happen millions of times per day. Is using `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` still the right approach? is there an equivalent of "try to update first, if that fails then insert the row"? (like an actual "UPSERT").

Comment: There is hardly any overhead of using insert on conflict even if it's an update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no variant of `UPDATE` that has the same behavior, for the simple reason that it would do exactly the same thing as `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`. Don't worry about the name.

If you have millions of updates for each row per day, you should worry much more about `VACUUM`.

If you can, do not index the attributes that will be updated frequently and create the table with a `fillfactor` lower than 100. The you can get the much more efficient &ldauo;HOT updates”, which will significantly reduce the amount of disk writes and `VACUUM` required.

Make sure to tune autovacuum to be more aggressive by lowering `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay`.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense. I'll make sure to tune autovacuum :)